# When is std::string_view::operator== really constexpr?

Tags: c++, gcc, c++17, libc++

According to [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view/operator_cmp), `std::string_view::operator==` is constexpr. I have trouble finding a situation for this to be true with current library implementations.

Here's what I tried:

```
#include <string_view>

constexpr char x0[] = "alpha";
constexpr char y0[] = "alpha";
constexpr auto x = std::string_view(x0, 5);
constexpr auto y = std::string_view(y0, 5);

constexpr auto a = std::string_view("alpha", 5);
constexpr auto b = std::string_view("alpha", 5);

int main()
{
  // a, b, x, y are all constexpr, operator== is constexpr
  // therefore I expected this to compile:
  static_assert(x == y);
  static_assert(a == b);
}
```

With gcc-trunk, this does not compile because in libstdc++ the operator== is not constexpr at all.

With clang-trunk this also fails because operator==() is declared constexpr, but uses char_traits::compare() which is not constexpr.

Are these bugs in the standard libraries? Or are my expectations wrong?

If my expectations are wrong, then how can I construct a string_view that can be constexpr-compared?

Comment: Guess that no compiler is fully C++17 compliant. Partly because the target is still moving, and the committee has a [meeting next week](https://isocpp.org/blog/2016/07/n4608) to sort things out.

Comment: The current implementations probably use `char_traits<CharT>::compare` to do the comparing. It will work faster than a manual loop at runtime. It could probably be done with some intrinsics.

Comment: According to [N3762](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3762.html), `operator==` is declared without `constexpr`.

Comment: The problem of how `constexpr` interacts with the C library is still largely unresolved, and there'll probably still be a number of changes.

Comment: See [P0426](http://wg21.link/p0426) and the linked LWG issue.

Comment: @kakkoko The latest revision I found is [N3921](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3921.html). There operator== is declared constexpr

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`string_view::operator==` uses `char_traits<CharT>::compare` to do the comparison.  `std::char_traits<char>::compare` is not constexpr, so the `operator ==` is not constexpr.

If you use an implementation of `char_traits` that implements a constexpr `compare`, then the comparison will be constexpr.

Note that there is a paper in front of the standards committee which proposes to make `std::char_traits<>::compare` (and other methods of that class) constexpr.

Comment: Keeping my fingers crossed for that paper! Do you know of an available implementation of `char_traits` that already implements a contexpr `compare`?

Comment: Write your own ;-). Seriously, I had to write a minimal one for the boost::string_view tests and it took me about 20 minutes.

Comment: P0426R1 was accepted, libstdc++ implements it in trunk, unfortunately string_view itself is still wrong implemented with a lot of missing constexpr.